# Find database records entered between two dates at specific times of each day

Tags: sql, oracle

I would love some help. I am trying to search an oracle database for records between two dates.
And for each the result set find records that were entered between 00 and 5 but also 21 and 23:59:59 (for a night shift). Here is a MWE I tried...

```
select TO_CHAR(date_entered,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Date Entered", other_rows FROM table_name 
WHERE (TO_DATE('&From_Time', 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= date_entered) AND (TO_DATE('&To_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date_entered)
--midnight to 5 am
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
--9pm to midnight
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 21 AND 23
```

But this doesn't seem to be giving the expected results. Thank you for your extra eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query looks fine, and using `extract()` is the correct way to isolate the (numeric) hour of a date.

But this:

```
--midnight to 5 am
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
```

Will actually give you dates whose time ranges from 00:00:00 to 05:59:59. You probably want this instead:

```
AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
```

Which will give you times until 04:59:59.

Also, parentheses around the conditions in the `where` clause are superfluous here.

Consider:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(date_entered,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Date Entered", 
    other_rows 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    TO_DATE('&From_Time', 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= date_entered
    AND TO_DATE('&To_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= date_entered
    AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
    AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date_entered AS TIMESTAMP)) BETWEEN 21 AND 23
```

Comment: if I get `invalid extract field for extract source`

Am guessing this means I have a different datatype (for date_entered).

Comment: @Sight: what is the datatype of column `date_entered`?

Comment: currently not able to describe the view but I am guessing `date`

Comment: @Sight: ok, well turns out `extract()` only works on `timestamp`s, not on `date`s. So we need to `cast()` first (as in your original attempt). I fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATE_ENTERED, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Date Entered",
    OTHER_ROWS
FROM
    TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    ( TO_DATE('&From_Time', 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= DATE_ENTERED )
    AND ( TO_DATE('&To_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= DATE_ENTERED )
--midnight to 5 am
    AND ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE_ENTERED,'HH24')) < 5
--9pm to midnight
          OR TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATE_ENTERED,'HH24')) >= 21 )
```